# Find all $\alpha$ such that the series converges

Tags: sequences-and-series, trigonometry, convergence-divergence

Find all values of $\alpha$ such that series $$\sum^\infty_{n=1} \left( \frac{1}{n \cdot \sin(1/n)} - \cos\left(\frac{1}{n}\right) \right)^\alpha$$ converges.

---

I used Maclaurin for $\sin$ and $\cos$ and got:

$$a_n = \left( \frac{1}{1 - \dfrac{1}{3!n^2} + \ldots} - 1 + \frac{1}{2!n^2} - \frac{1}{4!n^4} + \ldots \right) ^ \alpha$$

Put it together in one fraction seems to be a hard thing to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT:**

You are on the right track.  Note that

$$\frac{1}{1-\frac1{6n^2}+O\left(\frac1{n^4}\right)}=1+\frac1{6n^2}+O\left(\frac1{n^4}\right)$$

Hence, we see that

$$\frac{1}{n\sin(1/n)}-\cos(1/n)=\frac2{3n^2}+O\left(\frac1{n^4}\right)$$

Comment: I can't understand how to get the first statement.

Comment: @inquiro Note that $\frac{1}{1-x}=1+x+x^2 +x^3 +\cdots$.  Now, let $x=\frac1{6n^2}+O \left( \frac{1}{n^4} \right)$.

Comment: @AbdallahHammam What do you want to know about your answer?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

$$n\sin(\frac{1}{n})=1-\frac{1}{6n^2}(1+\epsilon_1(n))$$

$$\frac{1}{n\sin(\frac{1}{n})}=1+\frac{1}{6n^2}(1+\epsilon_2(n))$$

$$\cos(\frac{1}{n})=1-\frac{1}{2n^2}(1+\epsilon_3(n))$$

thus, when $n\to +\infty$, the general term of your series $u_n$, satisfies

$$u_n \sim (\frac{2}{3n^2})^\alpha $$

and by the limit comparison test,

$\sum u_n$  converges $\iff \;
\alpha>\frac{1}{2}$.